# How do we Pass the multiple selected values of a Slicer inside DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

Let's say I have a table like this - [Orders]

```
Date        Amount  Category
12/12/2017  100      A
12/12/2017  200      B
12/12/2017  300      C
1/1/2018    400      A
1/1/2018    500      B
```

And I have a slicer for Category.

If only one single Value is selected, then a measure like this will work

```
CALCULATE(SUM(Orders[Amount]),FILTER(ALL(Orders), Orders[Category] = SelectedValue(Category))).
```

When more than one value is selected, how would you pass that inside the DAX Measure?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
= CALCULATE(SUM(Orders[Amount])
      FILTER(ALL(Orders), Orders[Category] IN VALUES(Category)))
```

---

In most situations, you should just be able to write `SUM(Orders[Amount])` and Power BI will automatically do the filtering for you based on the slicer.

Comment: I've spent all morning looking for a solution to this, thank you, worked like a treat!